# update apps distributed to client raspberry pi

Tags: software-installation

I have an app that I have running on client raspberry pi's. The app was distributed using sd card. what steps do i need to do to update that app using the normal apt-get, which we use for just about any package ?
Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

**Hi there,
After hours of researching on how you can distribute/update apps through aptitude/apt-get, I managed to find this solution as quoted below.**

> You can do this by uploading your program to launchpad and creating PPA.
>
> PPA:
>
> A PPA is a Personal Package Archive, and is a method of distributing
>   software to users, without requiring developers to undergo the full
>   process of distribution in the main ubuntu repositories.
>
> PPAs can be used to extend the available software in ubuntu to both
>   programs that are not otherwise available in ubuntu, as well as to
>   allow newer versions, such as beta programs, that have not yet
>   undergone sufficient testing to be imported into the main archive.
>
> Quoted from Ubuntu website
>
> [There is a Launchpad PPA help file](https://help.launchpad.net/Packaging/PPA)
>
> To install your program, users will need to add the ppa to their
>   repositories like so:
>
> sudo apt-add-repository ppa:yourppaname and then after syncing the
>   package index with apt-get update they will be able to install it with
>   apt-get install

***I haven't tried this myself, but I hope this is the solution you are looking for!*
Best of luck,
Shayan Doust**